# Data extract from two sheets if it meets one criteria

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. These sheets are not in the same order for the data. I would like to insert the data on Sheet 2 from column G if the data on column E matches the same data on Sheet 1 column F.

Sheet 1 is the original file, and Sheet 2 is the unorganized file but it has similar column headers, the list of data are just not on the same exact rows for both sheets.

[image: 1st sheet]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in G2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F; output_result!E:G; 3; 0)))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E; output_result!F:G; 2; 0)))
```